# Question regarding inferiority complex

Tags: social-psychology, personality, behavior, jung

> "***The more one has feelings of inferiority, the more one has a power attitude, and the more one has a power attitude, the more one has feelings of inferiority***"

This above paragraph was said by Carl Gustav Jung.

I observed that some people try to show that they are more powerful and always wants attention in group of people and for that purpose they humiliate others and make them feel incomplete means they knowingly & unknowingly makes other person also inferior.

**Question 01** : Is such things are the symptoms of ***inferiority complex***?

Because they feel inferiority in their minds so there may be possibility that want to remove their inferiority in their mind by showing their power.

**Question 02** : How to deal with such people and what are the cure of such complex?

Answer (score 1):

"Inferiority complex" is an old idea from non-scientific study of psychology.

[If you look for recent papers](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_ylo=2018&q=%22inferiority+complex%22&hl=en&as_sdt=0,50), you'll find that most are either in very low-quality journals, occur as literary or similar analyses rather than real human psychology, or are puns/jokes/references to the concept rather than actually about "inferiority complex" in psychology. For example, this one:

> Assimon, M. M., Cutter, G. R., & Bargman, J. M. (2022). The Non-Inferiority Complex: What Do Non-Inferiority Trials Tell Us?. Journal of the American Society of Nephrology, 33(4), 674-676.

A non-inferiority trial is a type of statistical design where instead of testing a null hypothesis that two treatments are not different and declaring a statistically significant result when you observe a difference larger than expected by the null hypothesis, you test a null hypothesis that two treatments are different by at least some margin, and declare a statistically significant result when you observe a difference smaller or in the other direction as expected by chance if the null hypothesis is true. This has nothing to do with "inferiority complex" in psychology, of course, but the author gave the paper a cute name making reference to the old-fashioned idea.

The idea of the inferiority complex goes back to [Alfred Adler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Adler), a contemporary of Freud. Reading about Jung, Freud, and other similar past figures in the field might be useful to understanding the *history* of psychology, but just like we don't use Galen or Aristotle in treating modern medical patients, I'd highly recommend against using Jung or Freud to understand actual psychology.

> I observed that some people try to show that they are more powerful and always wants attention in group of people and for that purpose they humiliate others and make them feel incomplete means they knowingly & unknowingly makes other person also inferior.

It sounds like you are describing bullying behavior. There are lots of explanations for bullying, but generally the attempts to scientifically link perpetration of bullying to low-self esteem are mixed or show very modest associations, for example:

[Tsaousis, I. (2016). The relationship of self-esteem to bullying perpetration and peer victimization among schoolchildren and adolescents: A meta-analytic review. Aggression and violent behavior, 31, 186-199.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1359178916301355)

Comment: *"I'd highly recommend against using Jung or Freud to understand actual psychology"* From my understanding of psychoanalytical theory, I totally disagree. You need a fully balanced understanding of both psychoanalytical and non-psychoanalytical theory to fully understand where the concepts come from and how they were developed and still being adjusted. https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2248/7604 An inferiority complex could very well be in play in the scenario put forward and you completely downplayed it.

Comment: @ChrisRogers , i agree with your statement. Inferiority complex is very big problem among teenagers and most of suicide are probably done by teenager because they think they are unimportant, useless and feel inferior..., We should not ignore such things...., When we read the suicide notes of those teenager then we can easily understand that inferiority complex was there

Comment: @ChrisRogers To be scientific one would need to back this up with **systematic evidence**, not just thinking about it and writing it down on the page or basing things on single anecdotes.